# Calculating long intervals of Interest with Simple Interest Formula

Tags: loans, calculation, financial-literacy, terminology

My last post [Calculating long intervals of Interest](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54837/calculating-long-intervals-of-interest/54874#54874) calculates interest using compounding formula. But what about calculating simple interest accrued where the day count is actual/actual and it goes through two different year lengths (365 to 366 or vice versa)

For example

What is the interest accrued between December and January

```
Loan has principal of $100,000
Interest rate of 8% compounding annually
Disbursal Date is December 15 2015
Initial Payment Date is January 15 2016
```

What I would normally do

```
Interest Accrued = Principal * Interest * Time
                 = 40000 * 0.085 * 31/366
```

What I think it should be but I'm not entire sure

```
2015 has 16 days
2016 has 15 days

Time = 16/365 + 15/366

Interest Accrued = Principal * Interest * Time
                 = 40000 * 0.085 * (16/365 + 15/366)
```

Is this the correct way of calculating interest with two different year intervals when it has actual/actual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of what [day count convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention) you are using, it seems that the formula your are is the [Actual/Actual ISDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_count_convention#Actual.2FActual_ISDA) formula. But since there is more than one form of doing this, I don't think there is a truly correct way.

IMO, if you don't have any particular reason to not do so, I'd rather stick with the conventional 365 days a year.